# next-i18next not rendering client side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

i am updating dependencies for a client and i updated nextJS from `getInitialProps` to `getServerSideProps`.

Therefore, i had to update next-i18next.

**Before**, here's what was used in getInitialProps for translations :

```
class Homepage extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps ({ store }) {
        store.dispatch(PlansCreators.plansGet())

        return {
            namespacesRequired: ['common', 'containers', 'home', 'form']
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Head>
                    <title>{`${config.DEV ? 'DEV - ' : ''} ${t('SEO.BASE.TITLE')}`}</title>
                    <meta name='description' content={t('SEO.BASE.DESCRIPTION')} />
                    <meta property='og:title' content={`${t('SEO.BASE.TITLE')}`} />
                    <meta property='og:description' content={t('SEO.BASE.DESCRIPTION')} />
                    <meta property='og:image' content='' />
                </Head>
                <Home />
            </Layout>
        )
    }
}
```

---

**After** my update :

```
function Homepage() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>{`${config.DEV ? 'DEV - ' : ''} ${t('SEO.BASE.TITLE')}`}</title>
                <meta name="description" content={t('SEO.BASE.DESCRIPTION')} />
                <meta property="og:title" content={`${t('SEO.BASE.TITLE')}`} />
                <meta property="og:description" content={t('SEO.BASE.DESCRIPTION')} />
                <meta property="og:image" content="" />
            </Head>
            <Home />
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getInitialProps({ locale, store }) {
    store.dispatch(PlansCreators.plansGet())

    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common']))
        }
    }
}
```

The translations seems to be working during the render, but only for like 0.5 seconds. Then, it come back to `SEO.BASE.TITLE`... So i thought it was the `localePath` in the `next-i18next.config.js` that was involved, but that's not the case.

Here's my `next-i18next.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['fr', 'en'],
        defaultLocale: 'fr',
        reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        localePath:
    typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? require('path').resolve('./public/locales')
        : '/locales'
    }
}
```

I also have this error in my javascript console (browser side) :

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 i18next: hasLoadedNamespace: i18next was not initialized
```

and

```
i18next::translator: key "SEO.ACCOUNT.TITLE" for languages "fr" won't get resolved as namespace "common" was not yet loaded This means something IS WRONG in your setup. You access the t function before i18next.init / i18next.loadNamespace / i18next.changeLanguage was done. Wait for the callback or Promise to resolve before accessing it!!!
```

Do i miss something ? Do i have to build a backend even with next-i18next ? I just follow the documentation 3 times...

Here are my versions :

`"i18next": "^22.0.6",`

`"react-i18next": "^12.0.0",`

`"next-i18next": "^13.0.3",`

---

Here's how i wrap my `App` in `_app.tsx`

```
export default compose(
    withRedux(bootstrapStore),
    withReduxSaga,
    withRouter
)(appWithTranslation(MyApp, nextI18NextConfig))
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hello bro did you find any solution?
I am facing similar kind of Issue.